# Unable to access navigation on child render

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Can please someone explain to me why I can access this.props.navigation on the main render and not on the child, also please let me know how can I pass this parameter to the other render method

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

renderContent() {
  return (
    <View>    
        <Button
        title="ProfileScreen"
        onPress={() =>
        navigate('ProfileScreen')
        } />   
    </View>
  );
}

render() {
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  return (
        <ReactNativeParallaxHeader
          headerMinHeight={24}
          renderContent={this.renderContent}
        />
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen
```

I tried implementing an arrow function but still nothing happens and got undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're defining navigate inside the render() method.

This should work

```js
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

let navigate;

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    navigate = props.navigation.navigate;
}


renderContent() {
  return (
    <View>    
        <Button
        title="ProfileScreen"
        onPress={() =>
        navigate('ProfileScreen')
        } />   
    </View>
  );
}

render() {
  
  return (
        <ReactNativeParallaxHeader
          headerMinHeight={24}
          renderContent={this.renderContent}
        />
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Comment: I think you don't have to define navigate outside constructor, so I get rid of that `let navigate` and it worked